# Chord of fixed length traveling around a Jordan curve

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Let $C$ be a Jordan curve with nice enough properties whenever necessary (e.g. smooth, or just rectifiable, perhaps). I am interested in knowing how long can a chord be that "traverses" the Jordan curve once around, with both ends attached to the curve. By this I mean we can move around the chord such that both endpoints pass over every point on $C$ continuously. The chord can intersect the curve. See [this](http://www.math.pitt.edu/%7Etroy/sflood/holditch.pdf) article on Holditch's theorem for some nice pictures to give some intuition.

Edit:

A better way to define traversing the curve is as follows. Let $M$ be the space of unordered pairs of points of $C$. It is known that $M$ is a Möbius strip, with boundary corresponding to pairs of identical points. Let $\phi:M \to [0,\infty)$ be the square of the distance between a pair of points. If $C$ is smooth, so is $\phi$. For some regular value $l \geq 0$ of $\phi$, its pre-image consists of embedded circles in $M$.

Now we say that a chord of length $l$ can traverse $C$ if $\phi^{-1}(l^2)$ contains a circle component homotopy equivalent to the boundary.

End edit.

There is a simple upper bound to the length of such a chord for arbitrary Jordan curves. Let $d_\theta$ be the largest distance among the set of pairs of points on the curve that form a line at an angle $\theta$, and let $d$ be the minimum $d_\theta$ over all angles. Then a chord longer than $d$ cannot traverse the whole of $C$. Indeed, let $\theta_0$ be an angle such that $d_\theta = d$. Then if the chord traverses the whole of the curve, it will have to rotate a full $2\pi$ and have at some point an angle $\theta_0$, but $d$ exceeds the maximum length at that angle.

I'm guessing that for convex curves, this bound is attained. I was hoping this would also hold for smooth Jordan curves, but I could find non convex counterexamples. I do not know if there exists some arbitrary Jordan curve where there are no chords of any length (besides the trivial one of length $0$) that can traverse the curve, which perhaps could be the case for curves of infinite length, or other highly pathological examples.

So my main question is:

> For a nice enough Jordan curve, what is the longest chord that can traverse it, as defined above?

Comment: Why does the chord make a full $\pi$ rotation? Why does it even move continuously in the sense that we can choose the second endpoint continuously depending on the first one?

Comment: Sorry, typo, it should be $2\pi$. But a rotation by $\pi$ is enough to ensure it covers all angles. As for continuity, I am assuming that as well, and I should have included that. I'll edit this in, thanks.

Comment: But still, I don't understand how to actually prove that the angle makes a full rotation, and not going back at some point. Also, I think the question of continuity is quite interesting.. perhaps it shouldn't be swept under the rug?

Comment: If the chord is small enough to traverse the whole curve, it is possible that it "goes back at some point", i.e. one of the points (not both) moves in retrograde. I believe this is discussed in some of the examples in the linked article. If you mean that both points travel backwards at some point, this is part of the problem when the chord is too long to traverse the curve. In this case we do not necessarily have a full rotation.

Comment: But perhaps I'm misunderstanding your point. Do you mean that, even when the chord is capable of traversing the whole curve, it might not make a full rotation? To be honest I also assumed this because it seemed to me that it is trivial, but thinking about it, it might require something more. I'll give it a try and see if I can come up with something simple.

Comment: Yes, that is what i meant. However it seems i have a proof: we have $\gamma,\delta:S^1\to R^2$ - curves with the same image, but we never have $\gamma(t)=\delta(t)$, since we assume that the chord is non-trivial. 

If the vector $\gamma(t)-\delta(t)$ does not make a full rotation WLOG $\gamma(t)-\delta(t)$ is never horizontal. If $\gamma=(\gamma_x,\gamma_y)$, and same for $\delta$, this means that $\gamma_y$ is never equal $\delta_y$.

Comment: Since these are continuous functions on a connected set $S^1$, we can assume $\gamma_y>\delta_y$. Since $S^1$ is also compact, both functions attain maximum, and maximum of $\gamma_y$ is strictly greater than that of $\delta_y$. This however contradicts the fact that $\gamma$ and $\delta$ have the same image.

By the way i am not using explicitly that $\delta=\gamma\circ\alpha$ for some continuous $\alpha:S^1\to S^1$. Perhaps it follows automatically?

Comment: Nice. I'm assuming you mean that $\gamma$ is the first endpoint, $\delta$ is the second? Anyway, for continuity, I think it is necessary to assume it as part of the problem statement.

Comment: Yeah, $\gamma$ is the first endpoint, and $\delta$ is the second. So here is what i am wondering about now: we have that both $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are continuous have the same image and $|\gamma-\delta|$ is constant. Does it follow that $\delta=\gamma\circ\alpha$ for continuous $\alpha$?

Comment: I've given it some thought but I couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: Your question is related to this paper (and those that followed it): Goodman, Jacob E., János Pach, and Chee K. Yap. "Mountain climbing, ladder moving, and the ring-width of a polygon." The *American Mathematical Monthly* 96, no. 6 (1989): 494-510. [PDF download](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Goodman-Pach-Yap494-510.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for this. May I ask where I can find the papers that followed this one?

Comment: It seems *ring-width* of a polygon is similar to your question. If you Google Scholar the paper, you will find 34 later papers cite it, including "The mountain climbers' problem."